# How to restrict number of child elements in XSD 1.0?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have XML(1.0) like the following:

```
<Elements>
  <ChildElement1> 
      <GrandChildEle1/>
      <GrandChildEle2/>
      <GrandChildEle3/>
      <GrandChildEle4/>
  </ChildElement1>
  <ChildElement2> 
      <GrandChildEle5/>
      <GrandChildEle6/>
      <GrandChildEle7/>
  </ChildElement2>
</Elements>
```

All the child elements and grandchild elements have different names.

My question is: How to restrict the total number of `GrandChildElements` within the same rlements (not child elements) to be less than 5 in XSD? For example, if `Childelement1` has 3 `GrandChildElement` listed, then `ChildElement2` can only have up to 2 `GrandChildElements`.

Comment: XSD 1.0 cannot express such a requirement.  If you can use XSD 1.1, you could use assertions to impose that sort of constraint.

Comment: I am using VS2012, is there a way to enable XML 1.1 in VS? Thanks!

Comment: It's **XSD 1.1**, not XML 1.1, but, no, Microsoft does not support XSD 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. yes, i meant XSD 1.1.

Comment: So, with only XSD 1.0, sorry, you'll have to enforce such a constraint outside of the schema.